# 500 error after upgrading from 5.0 to 5.4 and adding empty functions.php

Tags: functions, 500-internal-error

I've finally managed to upgrade a WP site from v5.0 to v5.4. The only issue left is when I create an empty `functions.php` file I get 500 error.

Does someone have an idea why is that? Thanks.

Update:
My goal is to place the following into `functions.php`:

```
function my_acf_init() {
  acf_update_setting('google_api_key', $_ENV['GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY']);
}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');
```

Comment: So there was no functions file before and now there is a blank file?  Is the functions file at least a valid PHP file?  `<?php` as the first line.

Comment: Why do you need to do that if it creates an error?

Comment: 500 errors are just Apache/Nginx's way of saying something in PHP went wrong. Look at the PHP error log for the actual error message

Comment: @jdm2112 My goal isn't to add an empty `functions.php` obviously. I have gradually removed its content to see where it breaks. I wanna add an `add_action` call to inject env variable value to Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: @TomJNowell I'll have a look. It is on Heroku and I haven't been able to find it quickly (command `heroku logs` didn't show it).

Comment: Removing code in pieces to find the offending section is not very efficient.  If you are actively developing this site the PHP log is your friend. 
 I have no experience with Heroku but this might help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to print the error message by adding the following to the `functions.php`:

```php
function exception_handler($exception) {
    echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

For some reason logs did not include the error details before.
The error is `call to undefined function is_blog_installed()` which I have no idea why's that. :D